# Education entries on Careers can't have durations of 1 year or less

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I entered my education details onto my Careers profile back when it accepted text input for dates.

When editing or creating education entries, there are now combo boxes to select the start and end years, however unlike the previous textbox system, they don't accept a start and end year that are the same.

This is a problem in the case of qualifications that start and end in the same year, since new ones can no longer be created, and old ones can no longer be edited.

Procedure to reproduce:

- Navigate to http://careers.stackoverflow.com
- Navigate to CV editing page
- Edit an existing education entry or create a new one
- Enter some details, ensure start and end years are both the same
- Attempt to save changes

Comment: William - When could qualifications not be created, or existing edited?

Comment: @user66001 At the time I created this question, it wasn't possible to edit or create qualifications that started and ended in the same year.

Comment: Was actually meaning, during what time period (or more to the point, why was there a time period) that this wasn't possible.

Comment: @user66001 I am unsure as to how long, but it was definitely possible when I first created my Careers account (November 2011), as I had an entry with the same start and end year. When I went to edit the entry I encountered the problem that led me to ask this question. When researching on the topic I did encounter news of some kind of a date format update which is probably when they changed it, however unfortunately I can't remember when that was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now possible. The start and end date can now be the same.

Comment: surely a feature that is 'by design' which a user finds confusing is a usability bug? isn't the right answer to allow both behaviours as ways of specifying a single year?

Comment: @jheriko - Seems that both methods (Choosing blank year and same as start year) are now possible (Respectively - One displays just the start year; The other, a range of whatever start and end year specified)