# Careers certifications not allowing less than one year course

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, error-message, cv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Education entries on Careers can’t have durations of 1 year or less](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156618/education-entries-on-careers-cant-have-durations-of-1-year-or-less)

When adding ones Certifications on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit, if one studied and got certified in less than a year, trying to enter in the same starting year and ending year gives error `"End date must be after start date"`.

Unless I am misunderstanding the meaning of the date range, shouldn't this be changed to allow the same start and end years?

Comment: I think the certification date is for how long the certification is valid, not when you started/ended the program

Comment: Thanks. Then perhaps this should be more clearly stated?

Comment: Thinking more about this, can conceivably believe that a certification could only be valid for a year, and if not renewed, is also an issue for the status quo.

Comment: If this field is meant to indicate how long the certificate is valid then it *needs* to allow more time into the future, some certificates are valid for a couple of years.

Comment: @faker - It does, 10 years I think. Issue is if A) It is only valid for a year, B) Stating that this field is for certification validity, and not (what I thought it was) years of study.

Comment: @user66001 no, I wanted to add one today and the last possible *to* year is 2013.

Comment: @faker - My apologies. Guess I was remembering the large number of years that I have now discovered exist in the past, in those drop downs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to indicate one year, leave the other year blank.

Update: you can now do this. Check the duplicate question.

Comment: I'll repeat the comment made by jheriko the [*last time*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156618/education-entries-on-careers-cant-have-durations-of-1-year-or-less) this issue arose (and was marked [meta-tag:status-by-design]); this is a usability bug and is non-standard from every other date-range field I've used in my life.

Comment: @Matt - Seems that both methods (Choosing blank year and same as start year) are now possible (Respectively - One displays just the start year; The other, a range of whatever start and end year is specified)